# Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition, during insert from RadGrid Insert Panel into Table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, radgrid

Below is the **Stored Procedure** I am using to Insert Records into Database Table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SDM_Insert_BU]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @BUName as nvarchar(500),
    @BUShortName as nvarchar(500),
    @BUfoCompanyID as nvarchar(50),
    @BUfoStatusID as nvarchar(50)

    AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @BUID as nvarchar(50)
    --SP to generate new ID 
    EXEC dbo.SDM_Assign_RunningNo
    @TableName='SDM_Master_BU',
    @NewID = @BUID OUTPUT


    INSERT INTO SDM_Master_BU
    VALUES (@BUID, @BUName, @BUShortName, @BUfoCompanyID, @BUfoStatusID)

    SELECT @BUID as BUID

END
```

Below is the **Table structure** in which I have to insert the records from RadGrid (Insert panel):

[image]

here, `BUfoCompanyID`, `BUfoStatusID` are the foreign keys in Table. 
Below is the **c# code** I am using to insert the records:

```
public DataTable InsertBU(string BUName, string BUShortName, string BUfoCompanyID, int BUfoStatusID)
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterSASDB"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[SDM_Insert_BU]", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BUName", BUName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BUShortName", BUShortName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BUfoCompanyID", BUfoCompanyID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BUfoStatusID", BUfoStatusID);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return dt;
    }

    protected void rgBU_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;

            DropDownList clist = item.FindControl("ddlCompany") as DropDownList;
            string BUfoCompanyID = clist.SelectedValue.ToString();
            DropDownList slist = item.FindControl("ddlStatus") as DropDownList;
            int BUfoStatusID = Convert.ToInt32(slist.SelectedItem.Text);
            string BUName = (item["BUName"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
            string BUShortName = (item["BUShortName"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;

            InsertBU(BUName, BUShortName, BUfoCompanyID, BUfoStatusID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox_simple("Error", "Error!<br/>Please print screen and submit ITS.<br/> Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Below is the **HTML code**:

```
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgBU" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ShowStatusBar="true"
                    OnNeedDataSource="rgBU_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="rgBU_ItemDataBound"
                    OnInsertCommand="rgBU_InsertCommand"
                    EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" ImagesPath="~/App_Themes/MetroRed/Grid" GridLines="Both">

                    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"
                        InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">
                        <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="New" />
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton">
                            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>

                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BUID" HeaderText="Id" UniqueName="BUID"
                                SortExpression="BUID" ReadOnly="true" Visible="False">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BUName" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="BUName"
                                SortExpression="BUName">
                                <ColumnValidationSettings EnableRequiredFieldValidation="true">
                                    <RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" Text="*This field is required">
                                    </RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </ColumnValidationSettings>
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BUShortName" HeaderText="Short Name" UniqueName="BUShortName"
                                SortExpression="BUShortName">
                                <ColumnValidationSettings EnableRequiredFieldValidation="true">
                                    <RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" Text="*This field is required">
                                    </RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </ColumnValidationSettings>
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="BUfoCompanyID" UniqueName="BUfoCompanyID" HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="BUfoCompanyID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" Text='<%# Eval("Company") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" Width="240" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="BUfoStatusID" UniqueName="BUfoStatusID" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="BUfoStatusID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" Width="50">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="0" />
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="0" Value="1" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                            <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Delete this Projected?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                                ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" ConfirmDialogHeight="160px"
                                ConfirmDialogWidth="250px">
                            </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditFormSettings>
                            <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
                        </EditFormSettings>
                        <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
                    </MasterTableView>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

When I debug the Insert Code of RadGrid, every time I get below error in Catch Block of `InsertBU()` method:
**Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

At Line: `da.Fill(dt);` 

I checked everything and all seems to be fine. Dont know why its throwing this error. 

Also, when I write SQL query for same thing, it works without any error(there I pass `BUID` through Insert SQL query). 
Please check the Stored Procedure, there Im passing 4 parameters in SP to insert, and `BUID` from `@NewID`, so
overall it is getting all 5 values to be inserted into Table then why again n again same error? Please reply

Comment: because the table has 6 columns.

Comment: is the ID column defined as an identity column?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes ID columns is identity column. It is autogenerated. I am only inserting 5 values. 4 from c# code and 1 from another Stored Procedure in above defined Stored Procedure. Please reply

Comment: Try to specify the column names in the insert clause. It's better practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that u have 6 columns in table and u are supplying only 5 to it.
In your case ID column is Not Null which means it should be supplied with value if it is not set to identity column . Set default value 1,1 if it is bigint or newid() if it is Uniqueidentifier

Comment: Thank you for the reply. And sorry for my late response. ID column is Not Null with data type `bigint` and is also set to `identity = yes`. Then why this error is coming ? ID is suppose to enter automatically while entering the records.

Comment: well then the error should can not insert null to colmn id or like no of values supplied is not equal to no of column specified.. so dont try to fool around